# Wordpress cart and product prise not showing in safari

Tags: php, css, wordpress, safari

My site is based on wordpress cms . it is a e-commerce site . i am using woocommerce plugin . site is working fine on all browser except safari .

on chrome site looks like

[image: cart view]

[image: product prices]

but when i use safari browser images looks like

[image: Cart view]

[image: Product price]

I am not getting any idea how to fix this issue . please assist me .

Comment: When I checked It is showing me in safari. Have you tried by clearing cache ?

Comment: R u using windows machine or Mac ?

Comment: I have cleared cache to . even i am getting same issue. can you share safari screenshot

Comment: [Screen shot](http://s28.postimg.org/5h3i710y5/temporary1.png)

Comment: what version you using of safari.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78866/discussion-between-user2916639-and-rohil-phpbeginner).

Comment: What about the console? Did it showing any errors? Please provide more infos